# Costomize range slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to customize range slider but not succeed.

I have taken a reference from : http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

I want to 75% of the selector width needs to cover prices from $0 to $1,000 with steps 1 and remaining 25% of the width needs to cover prices between $1,000 and $20,000.

The slider would be something like that:

`1.........................................|.................20000`

`1 2 3 4 ..........................1000 2000 .....20000`

How can I achieved this type of functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think jQuery UI Slider supports this; you'd have to hack up the source.

Comment: i have solved this problem, i am using another slider that's have similar functionality as i want, here is link of that : http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/

Comment: If you solved the problem, write and accept an _answer_.